# How to check the number of questions left before hitting the cap?

Tags: support, feature-request, rate-limiting

Before posting questions, is it possible to check how many questions left before hitting the cap (50 questions in 30 days), and how things are like tomorrow, the day after tomorrow, ...? If not, may I make a feature request?

Is it generally acceptable using a sock puppet when hitting the cap?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I can see all the questions you have asked (so can you, of course) at http://math.stackexchange.com/users/1281/tim?tab=questions&sort=activity --- I guess you'd have some work to do to see when you posted each question, but just that page lets you see how many of your questions have been active in any given period, which gives you a bound. And I, for one, am strongly opposed to sock puppetry.

Comment: It suffices to sort your question by clicking on [newest](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/1281/tim?tab=questions&sort=newest) and you can see that you have asked 30 questions since November 26; since each page contains 30 questions. (Not including deleted questions.) When you go to the second page, you see questions 31-60. So you just have to count 10 questions from the bottom of the second page. (Asked on November 12, if I counted correctly.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A similar question [was asked on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96610/155238) and best I can tell there is no current indicators.

> Is it generally acceptable using a sock puppet when hitting the cap?

**Absolutely not**. The deliberate circumvention of built-in limits in the community will lead to the account being suspended.

Comment: Thanks! When hitting the cap, will deleting some questions from the past 30 days help to post new questions again?

Comment: @Tim: I'm not sure. I've forwarded your question along and someone who knows may come and answer it in a bit.

Comment: @Tim Hi, I'm a Community Coordinator at Stack Exchange. No, deleting questions will not affect it - we do include deleted questions in the count for your limit. This does make [Martin's trick above](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6788/how-to-check-the-number-of-questions-left-before-hitting-the-cap/6797#comment24302_6788) inaccurate if you have deleted questions in play.